# Validate string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, oop

**I am trying to solve the following problem:**

Given a string str, the task is to check if the string is a valid
identifier or not. In order to qualify as a valid identifier,
the string must satisfy the following conditions:

It must start with either underscore(_) or any of the
characters from the ranges [‘a’, ‘z’] and [‘A’, ‘Z’].
There must not be any white space in the string.
And, all the subsequent characters after the first character
must not consist of any special characters like $, #, % etc.

**Examples:**

Input: str= “_code123”

Output: Valid

Input: str = “123code_”

Output: Invalid

**My attempted solution, which works:**

```
def isValid(str1, n):
    # If first character is invalid
    if (((ord(str1[0]) >= ord('a') and
          ord(str1[0]) <= ord('z')) or
         (ord(str1[0]) >= ord('A') and
          ord(str1[0]) <= ord('Z')) or
         ord(str1[0]) == ord('_')) == False):
        return False

    # Traverse the string for the rest of the characters
    for i in range(1, len(str1)):
        if (((ord(str1[i]) >= ord('a') and
              ord(str1[i]) <= ord('z')) or
             (ord(str1[i]) >= ord('A') and
              ord(str1[i]) <= ord('Z')) or
             (ord(str1[i]) >= ord('0') and
              ord(str1[i]) <= ord('9')) or
             ord(str1[i]) == ord('_')) == False):
            return False

    # is a valid identifier
    return True


# Driver code
str1 = "_code123"
n = len(str1)

if (isValid(str1, n)):
    print("Valid")
else:
    print("Invalid")
```

How can I make the above code follow **OOP principles**, without so many nested ifs?

Comment: You could use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Comment: Show some input examples and expected output

Comment: @DevScheffer Check the driver code. It has an example

Comment: I mean more than just one example, some valid and invalid cases

Comment: @DevScheffer Added the example, but your solution doesnt seem to work if  _ is at the end of the expression.

Comment: It works try to run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have some read on regex it will help a lot for this kind of problem.

https://regexr.com/

This site is great for practice

```py
import re
def isValid(str1):
    res=re.match(r'^[_A-Za-z]\w+$',str1)
    return res
    
str1 = "_code123"
n = len(str1)

if (isValid(str1)):
    print("Valid")
else:
    print("Invalid")
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you please provide a bit of an explanation regarding what each of the reg ex expressions do? :)

Comment: Go to the site and put my expression the site will explain automatically

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use that code.

```py
if re.match('^[a-zA-Z_]+', line) is not None and re.match('^[\w-]+$', line) is not None:
    return True
```

`[a-zA-Z_]+` Your string may start with a-z, A-Z and underscore

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to say that nested ifs break OOP principles.

On the other hand, Python has certain features to help you out. First, you don't need to use `ord` so much because comparing two one-character strings does the same thing:

```
ord('a') < ord('b')
```

is equivalent to

```
'a' < 'b'
```

Second, Python allows you to chain math comparison operators, so instead of

```
'a' < 'b' and 'b' < 'c''
```

you can just type

```
'a' < 'b' < 'c'
```

But there is still an easier way: using the isalpha and isalphanumeric methods, you can avoid using the comparison operators, converting your code to:

Also, Python allows you to work directly on each character while looping by using the `for c in str` construct, saving you much indexing.

A more natural implementation of your code would be:

```py
def is_valid(str1, n):
    if not (str1[0] == '_' or str1[0].isalpha()):
        return False

    for c in str1[1:]:
        if not (c == '_' or c.isalnum()):
           return False

    return True
```

You could even use a list comprehension for the second part, by doing:

```
if not all(c == '_' or c.isalnum() for c in str1[1:]):
   return False
```